# How to develop a C++ project using codeblocks with separate Linux and Windows computer?

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc, codeblocks

I am developing a C++ application using code::blocks. At the institute, we have debian systems and all my files (source, input etc) are on the institutes servers. The servers are *nix based but I am not sure about the details that might be relevant here. My personal laptop is running windows 10. I can map the network drives to my laptop and then use code::blocks to work on the project.

Problem is, on my windows machine I have to Cygwin GCC but on the debian systems I have GNU GCC. If I open the project using code::blocks in Windows, then the 'project.cbp' files is overwritten to use Cygwin, and reverse if I open the project in linux.

As a result, when I make a switch between OS, I have to, sort of, re-establish the project (in linux this means reloading all files, and in windows I need to create a new project) which is a bit irritating. Is there any possible setting through which I can use the project in both windows and linux simultaneously? I imagine that if I can install GNU GCC in windows (which I think is not possible) or cygwin in debian (which I also think is not possible) then the problem would be solved.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the time to learn how to [Cmake on Codeblocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399512/cmake-codeblocks-hello-world-basic-example).

With Cmake, you can use the script to decide how to treat every different operating system.

Comment: I am not sure that I understood it perfectly. From what I get, the essence is that I generate a cmake-file (like the makefile?), which would then can be used to generate a project.cbp corresponding to my OS environment? Then I can just open this .cbp file to load the project in code::blocks?

But, given that I work in one folder, there could only be 1 project.cbp file. So, would it be the case that every time I switch os, I would have run cmake again and then reload the project into eclipse?

Comment: I don't use codeblocks, but Qt Creator, so I can't tell you how to do it. But since Codeblocks supports Cmake (big time), you should totally read on how to use cmake there. Basically Cmake generates a makefile for you on any operating system, and codeblocks should be able to read the the Cmake file to open your project.